# Finding a research internship with little prior experience

Tags: research-process, research-undergraduate, internship

I am a second year physics major student and I know for sure that I want to stay in academia and become a scientist, so I have started to search for research internships(abroad) and do research with my profs at my university (in Kazakhstan).

However, in the application there are documents like a description of your research or computational experience, which I don't have, except for my classes as Programming I and one year of research work with an engineering professor with no result. I can ask for a recommendation letter from this professor and that's it, but regarding computational work and research I can say only that I know C++.

Since doing that research work I realised that I don't really like engineering and want to pursue theoretical physics, Where I don't have any experience except for studying general relativity under the mentorship of one professor. Due to wasting a year studying engineering, my GPA is 3.38.

How can I improve my situation and make my candidate for research internships(in the US/Canada) more attractive?

Comment: How is admission handled in your country/situation. Is it done by individual professors, or an admissions committee/system?

Comment: Studying GR as a 2nd year undergraduate with an engineering background is impressive. Is there any chance that professor could write you a reference letter or even take you on as a research student? And are you looking for opportunities in Kazakhstan or further afield?